# Django multiple image upload to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I have made a simple ecommerce site in Django where user is allowed to upload multiple images of a product. These multiple images are required to save in bucket S3.

Here models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    posted_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    size_chart= models.FileField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="")

class Product_Pictures(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="", default="null")
```

Here views.py:

```
def add_product(request):
   try:
       files = request.FILES.getlist('pro-image')
       size_chart = request.FILES.get('size_chart', False)

       product = Product.objects.create(user = user, title = request.POST.get('title'), description = request.POST.get('description'), size_chart= size_chart)  
   except Product.DoesNotExist:
       raise Http500()

   product = Product.objects.latest('id')  
   for photo in files: 
       add_product_pictures(dress, photo)    
   return redirect('/ads')

def add_product_pictures(dress, photo):   
    photo = 'images/'+str(photo)
    Dress_Pictures.objects.create(dress =  dress, file = photo)
```

So when I try to add a new product with multiple images, only one image gets upload to S3 bucket none else gets upload.  Though entry gets save in database and system throws no error. I have tried many ways to manage it but nothing is working it. I am not getting why all files are not getting upload to bucket. Do suggest me some way out.

Answer (score 0):

Should this line of code be `add_product(dress, files)` or `add_product(dress, photos)` ?

Comment: Yes this is "photo". I did a typo while writing here as I tried to clean code.